# SpamAssassin doesn't flag any e-mails; no spam headers in e-mail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, spamassassin, amavis

We use Amavis between Postfix and Spamassassin. Emails that contain GTUBE pass clean through Amavis even though they should be marked with their corresponding headers.

```
Sep 24 20:11:09 mail amavis[955]: (00955-01) Passed CLEAN {AcceptedInbound}, AM.PDP-SOCK [2a00:1450:4864:20::430] [2a00:1450:4864:20::430] /AM.PDP <ouremail@gmail.com> -> <root@domain.tld>,<a@domain.tld>,<b@domain.tld>, (2a00:1450:4864:20::430), Queue-ID: 35776C1517, Message-ID: <CALp=EQ6vmtqzDxWCMpAbLBTLRk+cv-MAryrkJD4=sfhJLLC5kw@mail.gmail.com>, mail_id: u3_KZ3ChAtSu, b: eXTUveck7, Hits: -, size: 2694, Subject: "Bitte", From: <ouremail@gmail.com> (dkim:AUTHOR), helo=mail-wr1-x430.google.com, dkim_i=@gmail.com, dkim_sd=20161025:gmail.com, 287 ms
```

This is my SpamAssassin config at /usr/share/spamassassin/local.cf

```
# This is the right place to customize your installation of SpamAssassin.
#
# See 'perldoc Mail::SpamAssassin::Conf' for details of what can be
# tweaked.
#
# Only a small subset of options are listed below
#
###########################################################################

#   Add *****SPAM***** to the Subject header of spam e-mails
#
# rewrite_header Subject *****SPAM*****


#   Save spam messages as a message/rfc822 MIME attachment instead of
#   modifying the original message (0: off, 2: use text/plain instead)
#
# report_safe 1


#   Set which networks or hosts are considered 'trusted' by your mail
#   server (i.e. not spammers)
#
# trusted_networks 212.17.35.


#   Set file-locking method (flock is not safe over NFS, but is faster)
#
# lock_method flock


#   Set the threshold at which a message is considered spam (default: 5.0)
#
required_score 1.0


#   Use Bayesian classifier (default: 1)
#
# use_bayes 1


#   Bayesian classifier auto-learning (default: 1)
#
# bayes_auto_learn 1


#   Set headers which may provide inappropriate cues to the Bayesian
#   classifier
#
# bayes_ignore_header X-Bogosity
# bayes_ignore_header X-Spam-Flag
# bayes_ignore_header X-Spam-Status


#   Whether to decode non- UTF-8 and non-ASCII textual parts and recode
#   them to UTF-8 before the text is given over to rules processing.
#
# normalize_charset 1

#   Textual body scan limit    (default: 50000)
#
#   Amount of data per email text/* mimepart, that will be run through body
#   rules.  This enables safer and faster scanning of large messages,
#   perhaps having very large textual attachments.  There should be no need
#   to change this well tested default.
#
# body_part_scan_size 50000

#   Textual rawbody data scan limit    (default: 500000)
#
#   Amount of data per email text/* mimepart, that will be run through
#   rawbody rules.
#
# rawbody_part_scan_size 500000

#   Some shortcircuiting, if the plugin is enabled
# 
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Shortcircuit
#
#   default: strongly-whitelisted mails are *really* whitelisted now, if the
#   shortcircuiting plugin is active, causing early exit to save CPU load.
#   Uncomment to turn this on
#
#   SpamAssassin tries hard not to launch DNS queries before priority -100. 
#   If you want to shortcircuit without launching unneeded queries, make
#   sure such rule priority is below -100. These examples are already:
#
# shortcircuit USER_IN_WHITELIST       on
# shortcircuit USER_IN_DEF_WHITELIST   on
# shortcircuit USER_IN_ALL_SPAM_TO     on
# shortcircuit SUBJECT_IN_WHITELIST    on

#   the opposite; blacklisted mails can also save CPU
#
# shortcircuit USER_IN_BLACKLIST       on
# shortcircuit USER_IN_BLACKLIST_TO    on
# shortcircuit SUBJECT_IN_BLACKLIST    on

#   if you have taken the time to correctly specify your "trusted_networks",
#   this is another good way to save CPU
#
# shortcircuit ALL_TRUSTED             on

#   and a well-trained bayes DB can save running rules, too
#
# shortcircuit BAYES_99                spam
# shortcircuit BAYES_00                ham

endif # Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::Shortcircuit
```

Comment: Did you configure amavis to actually run spamassassin checks? Ubuntu ships rather conservative (do-nothing) defaults.

Comment: If you have logging turned on for Spamassassin you should see what is going wrong. That is the best way to make sure it is actually being called, and if it is called, why it is not marking the message as spam.